# Understanding the first section of Still for your love

Tags: translation, song-lyrics, song

Part 1    [Part 2](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100072/subete-wa-karamawari-overall-interpretation-of-still-for-your-love)    [Part 3](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100073/understanding-two-sections-of-still-for-your-love)    [Part 4](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100074/understanding-two-more-sections-of-still-for-your-love)    [Part 5](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100087/general-interpretation-of-still-for-your-love)

This time I'm cross-posting [this](https://mickgorroonyoutubeartisticsongtranslations.quora.com/Aaaand-yet-another-what-the-heck-does-this-song-say-post-I-m-so-various-Well-today-we-have-another-Japanese-song), and I'm already splitting it. The song this is about is [Still for your love](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/detective-conan-ost-still-your-love-lyrics.html) ([video](https://youtu.be/imo2c-85oyw)).

This question is about the following part:

> 何かが起こりそうな夜は
> 祈りをささげて　目を閉じなよ
> こんな月のとける夜に
> 愛され生まれてきたのとママは言った

Romaji:

> Nanika ga okorisou na yo wa
> Inori wo sasagete me wo tojina yo
> Konna tsuki no tokeru yo ni
> Aisare umarete kita no to mama wa itta

Possible translation:

> On a night when something seems to (be going to) happen
> Offer a prayer and close your eyes
> "On a night like this one when the moon melts
> [You?] were born being loved", mama said.

Questions:

1. "something seems to happen" or "it seems something will happen"?
2. What does it mean that "the moon melts"?
3. Do you think I got the extent of the quotations implied by the "to" in l. 4 right? Should I limit them to "Ai sare umarete kita", or expand them to all the way to the beginning of the section, or maybe just to l. 2 excluding l. 1?
4. Who is the subject of the first clause of l. 4? A [native Japanese on Quora](https://mickgorroonyoutubeartisticsongtranslations.quora.com/Aaaand-yet-another-what-the-heck-does-this-song-say-post-I-m-so-various-Well-today-we-have-another-Japanese-song?comment_id=60836676&comment_type=3) translated this clause as «Even love came into reality»: is this possible? Can "sare" be a variant of "sae" = "even, also"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. "something seems to happen" or "it seems something will happen"?

These English sentences seem almost the same to me. The original sentence is about the future. It's a mysterious/suspenseful night, but nothing has happened yet.

> 2. What does it mean that "the moon melts"?

It's not an idiomatic expression, so your guess is as good as mine. One possibility is that the moon looks blurry because of clouds or fog, but I'm not sure.

> 3. Do you think I got the extent of the quotations implied by the "to" in l. 4 right?

Yes, "こんな月のとける夜に愛され生まれてきたの" is what Mama said.

> 4. Who is the subject of the first clause of l. 4?

愛され is the masu-stem of 愛される, which is the passive form of 愛する, so it only means "to be loved". "You were born being loved" is the correct interpretation. There is no "even".

Comment: Why is there a "no" at the end of mama's utterance? <br> Also, should I take "yo wa" as plural, "On nights when etc etc"? Maybe that's not changing the meaning much though…

Comment: Why is it "yo wa" in l. 1 but "yo ni" in l. 3? Would "yo wa" in l. 3 make the night the subject of being born?