# About two sentences in Still for your love

Tags: translation, song-lyrics, song

[Part 1](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100071/understanding-the-first-section-of-still-for-your-love)    Part 2    [Part 3](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100073/understanding-two-sections-of-still-for-your-love)    [Part 4](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100074/understanding-two-more-sections-of-still-for-your-love)    [Part 5](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100087/general-interpretation-of-still-for-your-love)

This time I'm cross-posting [this](https://mickgorroonyoutubeartisticsongtranslations.quora.com/Aaaand-yet-another-what-the-heck-does-this-song-say-post-I-m-so-various-Well-today-we-have-another-Japanese-song), and I'm already splitting it. The song is [Still for your love](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/detective-conan-ost-still-your-love-lyrics.html) ([video](https://youtu.be/imo2c-85oyw)), and we're talking about the following part:

お願い遠くへ 行かないでと
なぜママは涙を流すの
ずっとずっとそばにいるよ
小さな心で思ってたけど
あの人に会うまでは
心ゆらされるまでは
そして全てはからまわり
未来がちぎれるのを見た

**Question 1: そして全てはからまわり**

What does this sentence mean in this song? Looking at the words, "Then everything was fruitless effort" would be my first guess, but why? What did this *ano hito* do to the poor singer that "everything was in vain"? And what "everything"?

[A Japanese on Quora](https://mickgorroonyoutubeartisticsongtranslations.quora.com/Aaaand-yet-another-what-the-heck-does-this-song-say-post-I-m-so-various-Well-today-we-have-another-Japanese-song?comment_id=60836676&comment_type=3) translates this as "Everything got twisted", and I somehow came up with "Everything loses its footing" some 11 years ago, but "karamawari" seems to mean "idling" or "fruitless effort", so how does that lead to either of these two translations?

And who could this *ano hito* be? Mother's lover? Pedo or other person violent to the child-daughter?

**Question 2: 心揺らされるまでは**

How should I translate this? I'd guess "Until [my] heart was shaken". That Japanese on Quora from the previous question translated it as "And he deprived my heart". AFAICT “yurasu” means “to shake, to sway”, how do we get from there to “to take away from, to deprive”? Deprive of what? Or did he mean "And he stole my heart", but again, how do we get there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want literal translations, you may want to stop relying on that Japanese person's translation. It's not bad at all to use words with similar meanings and do free translations, but it may be confusing to a learner who has to look up the meanings of words one by one.

And this is a song that allows multiple interpretations. I read the entire lyrics several times, but it's very hard to specify who あの人 refers to with confidence. People have various speculations:

- [rumania montevideoの「still for your love」は、22年で2度意味を変え、私の人生をも動かした！](https://note.com/47miku/n/n14ddee6aef21)
- [名探偵コナンの名曲 "still for your love" の歌詞の意味を私なりに解釈してみた](https://ameblo.jp/7beautiful4dirty-1rich/entry-12594193922.html)

1. あの人 = "The person I fell in love with". When I was little, I thought I would spend all my time with my mother. However, I fell in love, got a boyfriend, and had to choose between my mother and my boyfriend. I eventually decided to choose my boyfriend and left my mother, but I still wish her happiness.
2. あの人 = "My ex-husband's cheating partner". When I was little, my parents divorced, which was shocking to me. And this time I am going through my own divorce. but I still wish happiness of my separated husband and his new partner.

I personally like the first interpretation; this is probably a song about a person who has a new boyfriend and spend most of her time away from her family, still wishing happiness of her family.

---

> そして全てはからまわり

You know the meaning of から回り. It refers to an effort that does not yield meaningful results, like an engine that does not engage any gear. It just indicates her life is not going well even after becoming an adult. In that sense, "twisted" is not wrong.

> 心揺らされるまでは

The literal meaning is "Until [my] heart was shaken". It probably means "Until I fell in love with him", but other interpretations are possible.

Comment: Could you read [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/100103/5324) and comment if anything I say there is, in your opinion, unlikely or definitely not right?