# Understanding two more sections of Still for your love

Tags: translation, song-lyrics, song

[Part 1](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100071/understanding-the-first-section-of-still-for-your-love)    [Part 2](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100072/subete-wa-karamawari-overall-interpretation-of-still-for-your-love)    [Part 3](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100073/understanding-two-sections-of-still-for-your-love)    Part 4    [Part 5](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/100087/general-interpretation-of-still-for-your-love)

This time I'm cross-posting [this](https://mickgorroonyoutubeartisticsongtranslations.quora.com/Aaaand-yet-another-what-the-heck-does-this-song-say-post-I-m-so-various-Well-today-we-have-another-Japanese-song), and I'm already splitting it. I still give the full lyrics to the song, [Still for your love](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/detective-conan-ost-still-your-love-lyrics.html) ([video](https://youtu.be/imo2c-85oyw)) in case it's useful to have them for context:

何かが起こりそうな夜は
祈りをささげて　目を閉じなよ
こんな月のとける夜に
愛され生まれてきたのとママは言った

お願い遠くへ 行かないでと
なぜママは涙を流すの
ずっとずっとそばにいるよ
小さな心で思ってたけど
あの人に会うまでは
心ゆらされるまでは
そして全てはからまわり
未来がちぎれるのを見た

さぁ　裸足になって　大地けって
虹をこえて　空をつかんで

I wish　胸の十字架をにぎり　朝は
希望があなたにふりそそぎ　夜は
やわらかな光が　あなたを包み込み
明日{あす}への勇気を与える

幼い頃に　うえつけられた傷は重く
心にのしかかり
暗い狭い世界で　心ない世界で
ゆりかごに似たやすらかな　Final song

もう二度と　会えないとわかってても
色を変えてもつながってるから　空は
白い羽根身につけ　大きくはばたいて
未来を変えるよ　この手で

I wish　胸の十字架をにぎり　朝は
希望があなたにふりそそぎ　夜は
やわらかな光が　あなたを包み込み
明日{あす}への勇気を与える

I wish forever her great happiness la la la
Everynight in your dream I see you I feel you la la la
Tears stood in her eyes la la la Please don't cry la la la
Forever still for you, still for your love

The question is about the following part:

幼い頃に　うえつけられた傷は重く
心にのしかかり
暗い狭い世界で　心ない世界で
ゆりかごに似たやすらかな　Final song

もう二度と　会えないとわかってても
色を変えてもつながってるから　空は
白い羽根身につけ　大きくはばたいて
未来を変えるよ　この手で

Possible translation:

The wounds burned [into me] in childhood
Press heavily on my heart
In a dark and narrow world, in a heartless world
A gentle　Final song feeling like a cradle

Even knowing we can't meet again
Because our skies are connected even though they change colors
Tacking white wings to my body [and] flapping wide
I will change the future with these [two] hands!

**Question 1:**

What is a "final song"? Why is "nita" past tense and not non-past "niru"? Does this song no longer feel like a cradle? When did it then?

**Question 2:**

L. 2 can be read in like 4 ways:

1. "sora wa" as the subject of both tsunagatteru and kaete, as above;
2. "sora wa" as the subject of only tsunagatteru (because the sky is connected even though [we] change colors);
3. "sora wa" as the subject of only kaete (because we are still related/connected even though the sky changes color);
4. "sora wa" as part of the following line (which would then presumably happen in the sky, because having the sky tack wings onto itself doesn't seem to make much sense).

I would exclude #3 because of the position is "sora wa", but why the rest?

Comment: This is related to your question about 似た. [What are the general principles of using verbs to modify nouns (e.g. 焦げるトースト/焦げたトースト)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11975/43676)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is a "final song"?

It's a tough question, but since it's said before もう二度と会えない, perhaps it implies "This is my last message/song to you".

> Why is "nita" past tense and not non-past "niru"? Does this song no longer feel like a cradle? When did it then?

See:

- ["太ってる猫" vs "太った猫"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3361/5010)
- [What are the general principles of using verbs to modify nouns (e.g. 焦げるトースト/焦げたトースト)?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11975/5010)
- [Use of かける (N5 question)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/29671/5010)

> L. 2 can be read in like 4 ways:

Go with the first interpretation.

Comment: Is there any reason that #2 and #4 are wrong?

Comment: @MickG A person doesn't change color, and the sky doesn't wear wings.

Comment: couldn't "change colors" be used metaphorically for people?

Comment: @MickG You should not consider every unlikely possibily when seeing a "simple" sentence like this.